# What happens with a team time trial when a team does not have enough riders?

Tags: rules, cycling

In the 2015 Tour the France, the Orica-GreenEDGE team lost three riders in the first few stages. The team time trial only starts on the second Sunday, and as far as I know, the time of the fifth rider counts for the squad.

What happens if they lose two more guys, and will not be able to finish with 5 riders?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/which-riders-time-determines-result-in-team-time-trial/3328#3328) (which cites UCI regulations) it seems that rules concerning TTT may differ between various races.

Comment: If you meant to ask about TdF specifically, maybe you should add ([tag:tour-de-france]) tag.

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned Tour de France, here is what I have found about this in [Tour de France regulations](http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2015/docs/TDF15_Reglement-BD.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20160101184001/http://www.letour.com/le-tour/2015/docs/TDF15_Reglement-BD.pdf)). It is possible that different races have different rules. (This is explicitly mentioned in [this answer](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/3251/which-riders-time-determines-result-in-team-time-trial/3328#3328).)

> Article 24: Team time trial stage
>
> ...
> Each team’s classification position on the stage is established by the time set by their fifth rider across the finish line (accuracy is to 1/100th of a second).
> ...
>
> ...
> In the event where a team no longer has at least 5 riders, those remaining in the race are required to complete the course within the permitted finishing time provided for in Article 22 (Coefficient 6).
> The time taken into account for the team classification is the time of the final rider to finish recorded 5 times.
> ...

Answer (score 2):

Whenever a team has less than 5 riders to compete in the TTT, the time of the final rider counts.

I do not have an official source, but this question has been asked quite often over the past few days and this was the answer provided every time.

Furthermore, I believe, but I'm not 100% sure, when one or more of these riders finish out of time, the other riders will get the time of the last rider to finish in time.