# Has a team in a multi-stage cycling races ever had to drop out because they no longer met a minimum racer count requirement?

Tags: cycling, tour-de-france

In the ongoing Tour de France, UAE Team Emirates only has 4 cyclists remaining: their lead racer Pogacar and 3 of his team mates. I'm wondering: is there a minimum racer count requirement for competing teams in the Tour de France (or any other significant multi-stage race)? And did any team ever have to drop out because they no longer met that requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, no - riders race as individuals, the team is just for tactics and support and has no direct bearing on the results.

The exception to this is the (now dropped from the Tour de France) team time trial, where a team needed (I think) at least 5 riders to finish the stage. However, to avoid any issues with this the team time trial was always run in the first week of the race when it was incredibly unlikely that a team would have fewer than 5 riders available.

Comment: _Whenever a team has less than 5 riders to compete in the TTT, the time of the final rider counts._, from [What happens with a team time trial when a team does not have enough riders?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/10660/11439)

Comment: What do you mean by "(now dropped from the Tour de France)", have they said they'll never have one again?